# how to replace gulp.dest with absolute path?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have gulp function like this:

```
function copy() {
  return gulp.src(PATHS.assets)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets'));
}
```

it copies files to RELATIVE_PROJECT_DIR/assets;

I want to copy ot files to "F:/MyProject";

So, I replaced PATHS.dist into "F:/MyProject";

Now, the final output is:  "D:/RELATIVE_PROJECT_DIR/F:/Myproject"

which makes sense, as gulp.dest adds that relativity. So, I remove gulp.dest completely. But then I end up with the error:

> TypeError: dest.on is not a function

Why is that so?